# JPA base entity for modifiedBy and modifiedDate attributes

Tags: java, spring, jpa

In a spring boot project where I'm using spring data and JPA, all my entities have the modifiedByUser and modifiedDatetime attributes. Since I am being repetitive, I was thinking of creating a base class with those attributes, however I'm not sure if making all the entities extend a base class is a good idea since inheritance comes with its own issues.

I was also thinking in adding JPA entity lifecycle events to calculate the values for the modifiedByUser and modifiedDatetime fields. Is there any other suggested approach?

Answer (score 0):

As you said `modifiedByUser` and `modifiedDatetime` attributes would be repetitive things so you want to make it easy to use so I would suggest you to use the base class extending mechanism.

If you use JPA entity lifecycle events to calculate the values for the `modifiedByUser` and `modifiedDatetime` fields then it would be a repetitive things again and this is not the thing what you want.